# How to add an image to a java.awt canvas?

Tags: java, image, applet

I am trying to load an image but it never works. Ive tried importing numerous imports but they don't work. There is an error saying import expected. Even if I do import the library it doesn't work. Here is the code without the imports:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

BufferedImage background;

public class Ram extends Canvas{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Ram() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    setSize(1000,500);
    setBackground(Color.white);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is the declaration of

```
BufferedImage background;
```

is outside the class. In Java, all declarations must be inside a class. Just move it after this:

```
public class Ram extends Canvas{
```

and it will work.

To prevent this, get in the habit of pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> as you write code (assuming you are using Eclipse.) The auto indenting will help you catch errors like this.

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasted an hour looking for a solution.